# Is there a way to set rest configuration headers from property file values?

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel, spring-camel, ava

Here I'm trying to access the global property from properties file and set it in enableCORS header in rest configuration like

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"
    xmlns:prop="http://camel.apache.org/schema/placeholder"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans    
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
       http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring
       http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">

 <camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring" streamCache="true" id="service-v1.0.0"> 

<propertyPlaceholder id="a-properties" location="classpath:model.properties" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring" />
    <restConfiguration component="servlet" bindingMode="auto" prop:enableCORS="cors-header-enabled" /> 

</camelContext>
```

but when I do so. I'm getting an error like

> cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'prop:enableCORS' is not allowed to
>   appear in element 'restConfiguration'

How do I set and what should I change to make it work.

In my case there will be many service xmls and changing for each property will be tedious. Is there any workaround?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Huum, not sure placeholders are working for **all** tags (including restConfiguration)

The doc says:

```
The property placeholders is also supported in *many* of the Camel
Spring XML tags such as <package>, <packageScan>, <contextScan>,
<jmxAgent>, <endpoint>, <routeBuilder>, <proxy> and the others.
```

May be you could try the alternate syntax ?

```
<restConfiguration ... enableCORS="{{cors-header-enabled}}" />
```

Comment: No, it will fail while deployment saying the error posted.